# filedescriptor out of range in select() using requests

Tags: docker, python-requests, flask-restful

I have deployed code on 2 dockers in an ubuntu 16.04 instance and running the application on flask server, python 2.7.12

Previously i thought the error was from boto3 library, because i was uploading files to s3 so I removed that library dependency by using s3cmd os level commands to upload files but still i am getting the same error after a 100 to 500 hits, i am actually closing every file. I am even closing http connection by using "Connection" : "close" in the headers.

Is there a limit for number of requests from a docker ? and i am using threaded = True on flask is it because of that ?

Comment: Did you check how many files are actually open? I.e: `lsof -P <your process id> | wc -l`

Comment: i got so many results few of them are eventpoll and few are pipe . I am actually closing every file in the code . I dont know why they are open. is this because of threading in flask?